# PHP: Merge two MySql array result

Tags: php, mysql

i `fetch` id and name from categories table like this :

```
  |id|name| tag |desc|order|status|
  |1 |test| NULL|NULL|  1  |   1  |


  $i = 0;
  $allcats = Access::FETCH("SELECT * FROM " . CATS . "");
     $cats = array();
  foreach($allcats AS $row2){                                               
     $cats[$i] = array("name" => $row2['name'], "id" => $row2['id']);
  $i++;                                             
  }
```

i fetch category id for each news :

```
|id|catid|storyid|
|1 |  1  |   5   |

$groupcats = Access::FETCH("SELECT * FROM " . GROUPCATS . " WHERE  storyid = ?", $row['postid']);
```

Now, i need to print name of cat for storyid. i,e : i need to print `test`(catname) for story id 5.

How do can i print this?

Comment: That's great. What have you tried?

Comment: You need to research SQL JOINs.

Comment: @tadman: i dont have any idea!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier to do with with a `join` rather than in php. Something like,

```
$joinedcats = Access::FETCH("SELECT name FROM " . CATS . 
                            " JOIN " . GROUPCATS . " ON catid = id");
foreach($joinedcats as $row) {
     echo $row['name'];
}
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to get needed rows for each story:

```
"SELECT * FROM " . GROUPCATS . " LEFT JOIN " . CATS . " USING(categoryid) WHERE  storyid = ?"
```